# Form a list of boolean values based on if values from one list are in the other

Tags: python, list, boolean

Let's say I have a master list of strings

```
master_list = ['111111', '111112', '111117', '223335', '555667']
```

. I also have another list of strings

```
sub_list = ['555667', '111111', 111117']
```

. Based on these two lists, I want to return a list with boolean values, the same size as, and in the order of the master list based on if each value in the master list is in the sub list. In this case, the returned result would be:

```
[True, False, True, False, True]
```

Comment: `[x in sub_list for x in master_list]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
print([item in sub_list for item in master_list])
```

Output:

```
[True, False, True, False, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
master_list = ['111111', '111112', '111117', '223335', '555667']

sub_list = ['555667', '111111', '111117']

print([True if i in sub_list else False for i in master_list])
```

Comment: `True if i in sub_list else False`  is the same as doing `i in sub_list`